# Best performance when using multiple DataFrame's

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a master list `DataFrame` and then merging and removing data based on a change list `MasterFrame`.

I am very new to Scala so I have no doubt that I have not done things the most efficient way!

Basically just trying to establish how I can spend up the performance of the final `DF` as I have got a few `DataFrames` stacked on each other etc..
The record count is 40million+

```
 object SparkPi {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
                val conf = new SparkConf()
                val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

                //  Load CSV file into dataframe  
                val ChangeSet = sqlContext.read.json("/user/data/PythonAPITest/ChangeList.json")
                val Master = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "True").load("/user/data/PythonAPITest/master-landonline-title-memorial.csv")

                // Deleted = Joining Master -> Change set. Removes records from DF where ttm_id in ChangeSet
                val Deleted = Master.join(ChangeSet.where($"__change__" === "DELETE"), Seq("ttm_id"), "left_anti" )

                /* Create seperate lists. Lists indicate which records need to be added*/
                val InsertList = ChangeSet.select("LIST OF COLUMNS").filter($"__change__" === "INSERT")
                val UpdateList = ChangeSet.select("LIST OF COLUMNS").filter($"__change__" === "UPDATE")


                // UpdatedDeleted = joining Deleted -> UpdateList. Removes 
                val UpdatedDeleted = Deleted.join(UpdateList.where($"__change__" === "UPDATE"), Seq("ttm_id","sequence_no"), "left_anti" )
                val Updated = UpdatedDeleted.join(UpdateList, Seq("ttm_id","audit_id"), "leftanti").union(UpdateList)
                val Inserted = InsertList.join(Updated, Seq("ttm_id","audit_id"), "leftanti").union(Updated)

        }
}
```

This will be submitted to spark and stored on HDFS, so if there is a better way to do things, or a good place to look for tips & tricks please let me know